# String manipulation in java to get previous characters of a particular character

Tags: java

I have a string `"1/2,3/4,5/6"`. I need to get a `Set` of all the elements before `'/'`, i.e. above string should have a `Set` of `1,3,5`.

What is the best possible way to do it?

Comment: String Class's `split()` method is your friend. And what did you try so far ?

Comment: Your title suggests that you want the following: "123/4/5/67" to result in "345", is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String input = "1/2,3/4,5/6";
    String[] outputs = test.split("/\\d([,]*)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first split your string then get the data from there.

```
String line = "1/2,3/4,5/6";
String[] tokens = line.split(",");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String st : tokens) {
  list.add(st.split("/")[0]);
}
```

Comment: substring limit the number of character before the "/"

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```
    public static List<Integer> doubleSplit(String value){
        List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String s : value.split(",")){
            res.add(Integer.parseInt(s.split("/")[0]));
        }    
        return res;
    }
```